# sys.path.append | AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-2.7, sys

I'm trying to call a script that lives outside of python's env path. I thought I could use `sys.path.append()` using the folder path containing the script as the argument and then simply call the name of the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"N:\Common\Script\Drivers")
myscript.py
```

However, I can't get `sys.path.append` to work:

```
sys.path.append(r"N:\Common\Script\Drivers")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I've been over the python.org notes and can't find what I'm doing any wrong.

Comment: Your code should work fine, are you sure you're not running some previous version of it?

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio like a different version of python?

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio sys.version says 2.7.5

Comment: please provide the full code, I'm sure the error is not on `sys.path` line.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio I did, it seems to be working today.

Comment: Check if you're overriding `sys.path` somewhere

Comment: Yup. Other code running `sys.path = "something"` is the most obvious way to end up with this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you wrote `sys.path.append = (...)` instead of `sys.path.append(...)` somewhere earlier, but with so little code to go on, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I was running it in pythonWin to test the line of code so I don't have any more to provide, unfortunately.

Comment: @ShaunO Is `myscript.py` part of your script, or what is that? Is that line being executed?

Comment: @ it is just an example. I was doing this in an IDE so I just provided the path when trying to use sys.path.append(). I never got far enough to call the script within that directory.